# How to setup GitHub write-only access

Tags: git, github, access-control

I am looking to create a GitHub repository to collect Python scripts from around 30 people. However, I want these people to be able to push to the repository without seeing its contents, i.e. have write-only access. In other words, I am looking for the following access-controls:

- **Public : write**
- **Owner : read + write**

Is there a way to do this easily (or at all)?

I should also say that I have GitHub premium, so I have the abillity to make private repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this. You cannot make updates to a Git repository without first reading (cloning) the repository. Git deals in commits, and for a user to create a new commit, they need to have the *previous* commit and its commit ID.

Git is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: Are you aware of any tools, similar to Git, that would allow for this?

Comment: You could make one Github repository per person, but generally no. It would help if you described your actual usecase.

Comment: I am helping a professor teach a class, and we are trying to come up with a good way for students to submit work that we can then easily batch-grade.